# ServiceStack encountered exception: The underlying connection was closed: The message length limit was exceeded

Tags: .net, web-services, http, c#-4.0, servicestack

I have a client-side application, consume web service from server.

In one form of the application, it shows a list of tables, whose statuses are from the server, the form refreshing every 1 second. So it is acting like a real time page of all tables information.

However, after leaving the form there for about 20, 30 minutes, it starts to throw "The underlying connection was closed: The message length limit was exceeded".

I saw blog in http://code.logos.com/blog/2012/01/webexception-the-message-limit-length-was-exceeded.html, about setting the MaximumResponseHeadersLength, but I use ServiceStack, not sure where to set it, or how to solve this issue. Can anyone please help?

```
public IList<Table> GetAllTables()
{
   return ServiceClient.Get<EntitiesResponse<Table>>("/tables").Entities;
}
```

Comment: Btw I use JsvServiceClient.

Answer (score 4):

I was experiencing the same issue when using Apache Benchmark to test a few webservices running on ServiceStack.

I was able to get rid of the error by disabling the MiniProfiler.

Answer (score 2):

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) doesn't add any request limits itself, so the request limits you're hitting are from the ASP.NET Host.

See this answer to show you how to [increase ASP.NET's Request limits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3853785/85785).

Comment: I don't think increase the request limit can solve the problem. I've set the limit to 4GB, the problem still occur after about 1-2 hours. Obviously each refresh does not get much size from the request every 1 second.